# spring-boot-starter-graphql: getting 404 for /graphql endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I am using the new [Spring for Graphql](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/) in my Spring Boot application. My problem is, that the server always responds 404 when making a POST request to the `/graphql` endpoint.

These are my gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

I followed the steps in this [tutorial](https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/) to create the controllers (formerly known as resolvers, I actually changed all my old Graphql resolvers to the new @QueryMapping and @MutationMapping annotations)

This is the code for my StepController

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StepController {
  private final StepService stepService;
  private final TokenService tokenService;

  @QueryMapping
  public ArrayList<Step> getSteps(String templateId) {
    return stepService.getSteps(templateId);
  }

  @MutationMapping
  public Step createStep(StepInput input, DataFetchingEnvironment env) {

    return stepService.createStep(input, tokenService.getUserId(env));
  }
}
```

I am also using WebSecurity in my project, changed my deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to the [more modern way of doing this](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) by creating a Bean inside a SecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .configurationSource(request -> {
          var cors = new CorsConfiguration();
          cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200",     "electron://altair"));
          cors.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
          cors.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
          cors.setAllowCredentials(true);
          return cors;
        })
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/graphql").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/stomp/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        // this disables session creation on Spring Security
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

My GraphQl Schema is structured in `resources/graphql` in a folder structure, I had no problem with this before I switched to the new Spring Boot Graphql

[image]

**UPDATE** To be on the safe side: I deleted the whole folder structure and replaced it with one `schema.graphqls` file that has just the Login mutation and a query that is never used, just to avoid the `Query needed` compiler error

```
type Mutation {
  login(email: String!, password: String!): Login!
}

type Login {
  token: String
}

// unused, just to make the compiler happy
type Query {
  getLogin: Login
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.banner.location=classpath:logo.txt
spring.main.banner-mode=console
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.mail.host=mail.blablabla
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=no-reply@blablabla
spring.mail.password=blablalba
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.profiles.include=prod,dev

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=512KB
```

I hope I provided enough information as to how my project is set up. I would really appreciate any help that can solve this issue. I searched the whole evening yesterday, finally now posting this question here. I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Hello. Can you post your schema.graphqls? Make sure it's under resources/graphql directory. Also, could you add your application.properties?

Comment: I updated my question with the application properties, and a better screenshot of my graphql folder which is under the resources/graphql as it should be, I also tried to use one `schema.graphqls`file instead of the folders, doesn't work, same error. If I tinker with the structure and create a duplicate graphql type for example I get a compiler error, so I assume the graphql structure is okay

Comment: What was your final solution? I have quite the same Problem right now?

Comment: I didn't find a solution for this, and I decided to abandon the SpringBoot/Graphql backend in favor for NestJS. There were far too many deprecated libs due to updates, and many of the new implementations were undocumented, or hard to find. This happened a lot during the 6 months I worked on the project, and this problem was the final nail in the coffin for me to go with a different backend. The developer experience was just too bad... Sorry that I can't be of any help. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and used solution from this documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#execution.graphqlsource.schema-resources

**application.properties:**

```
spring.graphql.schema.locations=classpath*:graphql/**/
```

*3.1.1. Schema Resources
GraphQlSource.Builder can be configured with one or more Resource instances to be parsed and merged together. That means schema files can be loaded from just about any location.*

*By default, the Boot starter looks for schema files with extensions ".graphqls" or ".gqls" under the location classpath:graphql/**, which is typically src/main/resources/graphql. You can also use a file system location, or any location supported by the Spring Resource hierarchy, including a custom implementation that loads schema files from remote locations, from storage, or from memory.*

*Use classpath*:graphql/**/ to find schema files across multiple classpath locations, e.g. across multiple modules.*

https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/discussions/962

Answer (score -1):

Please add this property in application.properties file and try again.

spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but enabling graphiql is not working for this. Graphql and graphiql are 2 different things, I don't want to use graphiql because I am using Altair Graphql client.

Comment: ok is schema.graphqls file present inside graphql folder?

Comment: the location should be resources/graphql/schema.graphqls

Comment: Please read my question, I specifically updated it already BEFORE your suggestion (11:57 AM), saying that I tried using a schema.graphqls, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah  i have read that but you mentioned that deleted whole folder structure and replaced with schema.graphqls. So just want to check schema.graphqls file is inside resources/graphql folder?

Comment: Yes it is.. ;-)